# How is space allocated in memory for an array?

Tags: java

I've been looking online for several hours now for a fairly simple answer to how space is allocated in memory for an array...

Similarly, how are elements accessed in memory with indexing?

In other words, how is the index used to locate a specific array element in memory?

Comment: Java arrays are a type of object, and the [JLS Chapter - 10. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) may shed some light.

Comment: I don't understand what level of detail you need.
If you are interested in high level, please check:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html Otherwise you might as well look at an actual implementation:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the array name as just an address in memory, and all of the values are stored sequentially from there. If the array is multidimensional, each "element" in it is really just an address in memory pointing to the location of another array, so you have an array of arrays in that case.
Note: this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/what-does-a-java-array-look-like-in-memory/) will probably help you visualize this!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, like Objects, are allocated in the heap. Arrays are accessed much like they are in C or C++, with a base memory address and an offset.